# How to prevent iOS crash reporters from crashing MonoTouch apps?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, crash-reports, testflight

There are plenty iOS crash reporting libraries in iOS, including [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com) and [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net). If you don't want to depend on services, you can still use libraries like [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/). Binding these libraries is [fairly trivial](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Binding_Objective-C_Libraries) because their public API usually consists of a couple of classes with several initialization methods.

However, when trying to use TestFlight, and later HockeyApp in our application, our app began to randomly crash. Turns out, this *is* a known issue [reported](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=4120) [several](http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/Re-App-crashes-before-starting-td4657864.html) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865374/problems-getting-testflight-to-work-with-monotouch-app/7867056#7867056), but Xamarin doesn't warn about it, it is relatively obscure and we found it the hard way.

We have learned that **all iOS crash reporters prevent Mono from catching null reference exceptions:**

```
try {
    object o = null;
    o.GetHashCode ();
} catch {
    // Catch block isn't called with crash reporting enabled.
    // Instead, the app will crash.
}
```

Why does this happen? Quoting Rolf, a Xamarin developer,

> A null reference exception is actually a SIGSEGV signal at first. Usually the
>   mono runtime handles this and translates it into a nullreference exception,
>   allowing the execution to continue. The problem is that SIGSEGV signals are a
>   very bad thing in ObjC apps (and when it occurs outside of managed code), so
>   any crash reporting solution will report it as a crash (and kill the app) -
>   this happens before MonoTouch gets a chance to handle the SIGSEGV, so there is
>   nothing MonoTouch can do about this.

I'm sure many use TestFlight in MonoTouch apps without knowing it causes crashes.
[Isn't it ironic?](http://fgk.hanau.net/articles/ironic.html)

**How do you make crash reporting libraries *not* crash MonoTouch apps?**

Comment: If anyone is curious, these are our [HockeyApp bindings for MonoTouch](https://github.com/stampsy/hockeyapp-monotouch). [HockeyApp](http://hockeyapp.net) is not free but their support is really good (which is something I can't say about TestFlight) and generally we've been pleased with them. I added this fix to the sample project. (Disclaimer: We're not affiliated in any way.)

Comment: Co-founder of Crittercism here - we actually released an officially supported plugin for Xamarin here which works well with Mono - for example, it doesn't prevent Mono from catching SIGSEGV signals.  We let the Mono runtime handle those and then send those to Crittercism.  You can download it here: http://components.xamarin.com/view/crittercism

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Put this in `AppDelegate.cs`:

```
[DllImport ("libc")]
private static extern int sigaction (Signal sig, IntPtr act, IntPtr oact);

enum Signal {
    SIGBUS = 10,
    SIGSEGV = 11
}

static void EnableCrashReporting ()
{
    IntPtr sigbus = Marshal.AllocHGlobal (512);
    IntPtr sigsegv = Marshal.AllocHGlobal (512);

    // Store Mono SIGSEGV and SIGBUS handlers
    sigaction (Signal.SIGBUS, IntPtr.Zero, sigbus);
    sigaction (Signal.SIGSEGV, IntPtr.Zero, sigsegv);

    // Enable crash reporting libraries
    EnableCrashReportingUnsafe ();

    // Restore Mono SIGSEGV and SIGBUS handlers            
    sigaction (Signal.SIGBUS, sigbus, IntPtr.Zero);
    sigaction (Signal.SIGSEGV, sigsegv, IntPtr.Zero);

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal (sigbus);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal (sigsegv);
}

static void EnableCrashReportingUnsafe ()
{
    // Run your crash reporting library initialization code here--
    // this example uses HockeyApp but it should work well
    // with TestFlight or other libraries.

    // Verify in documentation that your library of choice
    // installs its sigaction hooks before leaving this method.

    var manager = BITHockeyManager.SharedHockeyManager;
    manager.Configure (HockeyAppId, null);
    manager.StartManager ();
}
```

Call `EnableCrashReporting ()` in the beginning of `FinishedLaunching` method.
Wrap this call in `#if !DEBUG` directive if you want.

---

### How does it work?

I followed Rolf's suggestion:

> One possible solution is to allow mono to handle all SIGSEGV signals
>   (technically speaking the crash reporting lib should either not handle
>   the SIGSEGV signal, or it should chain to mono's handler and not do
>   any processing by itself). If mono determines that the SIGSEGV signal
>   is not from managed code (i.e. something very bad happened), it will
>   raise a SIGABORT signal (which the crash reporting lib should already
>   handle and treat as a crash). As you can understand this is something
>   that has to be done in the crash reporting library.

And [Landon Fuller](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org)'s Objective C implementation:

```
#import <signal.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    /* Save Mono's signal handler actions */
    struct sigaction sigbus_action, sigsegv_action;
    sigaction(SIGBUS, NULL, &sigbus_action);
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, NULL, &sigsegv_action);

    // Enable the crash reporter here. Ie, [[PLCrashReporter sharedReporter] enableCrashReporterAndReturnError:],
    // or whatever is the correct initialization mechanism for the crash reporting service you're using

    /* Restore Mono's signal handlers */
    sigaction(SIGBUS, &sigbus_action, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sigsegv_action, NULL);

    return YES;
}
```

I used [Banshee source code](https://github.com/GNOME/banshee/blob/stable-2.2/src/Core/Banshee.Core/Banshee.Base/PlatformHacks.cs) as a reference point for how to call `sigaction` from MonoTouch.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Nic I just followed Landon's and Rolf's suggestions so credit goes to them!

Comment: This is great! I was using testflight before but removed it for this reason. Looking forward to getting proper in-the-wild crash reporting again.

Comment: Thanks very much for this, I wish it was more widely known, it would have saved me a lot of hassle

Comment: I tried it with Xamarin.Insights but it doesn't work, still I get app crashes.

Comment: @Peyman It's been a while so I can't guarantee the answer is still accurate. You should file an issue on their Bugzilla.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Xamarin.iOS 10.4 there's now a supported way of doing this:

```
static void EnableCrashReporting ()
{
    try {
    } finally {
        Mono.Runtime.RemoveSignalHandlers ();
        try {
            EnableCrashReportingUnsafe ();
        } finally {
            Mono.Runtime.InstallSignalHandlers ();
        }
    }
}

static void EnableCrashReportingUnsafe ()
{
    // Run your crash reporting library initialization code here--
    // this example uses HockeyApp but it should work well
    // with TestFlight or other libraries.

    // Verify in documentation that your library of choice
    // installs its sigaction hooks before leaving this method.

    // Have in mind that at this point Mono will not handle
    // any NullReferenceExceptions, if there are any 
    // NullReferenceExceptions on any thread (not just the current one),
    // then the app will crash.

    var manager = BITHockeyManager.SharedHockeyManager;
    manager.Configure (HockeyAppId, null);
    manager.StartManager ();
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the empty `try{}finally{` ?

Comment: @DavidRiha: It's to ensure the code won't be interrupted, because the mono runtime won't interrupt any code in a finally clause (if for instance another thread did a Thread.Abort (), that Abort call would only abort execution after the finally finished executing).