# App Exits on Real iPhone when an exception is thrown, and handled in button event?

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.ios

I have code that creates a button, (UIButton), in code and assigns it as a subview... everything works fine, except I was debugging my code to log exceptions, so I created a button called "Create Exception", the button handler does real simple code:

```
try
{
    object Q = null;
    Q.ToString();   
}
catch
{
    //Log.Exception ("Test", ex);   
}
```

Clearly, this won't do anything except get a Null Reference exception and catch it.. AND Ignore it...

In the simulator, all is well and good...  In a real device?   Yeah, App Exits with a null reference exception!!   WTF?

Latest Monotouch as of an update yesterday...

I'm concerned that all my exceptions won't catch and route to the Log.Exeception() code... Which is what I was trying to test in the first place...

This is in an anonymous function that is assigned to the Touch handler of the button..

-Chert

--- Update, Error:

> Date/Time:       2013-03-25 22:26:59.269 -0500 OS Version:      iPhone
>   OS 5.1.1 (9B206) Report Version:  104
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes: 0x00000000,
>   0x00000000 Crashed Thread:  1
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0: 0
>   TestApp                   0x00b5a2d8 load_method (aot-runtime.c:2661) 1 
>   TestApp                   0x00b5ae86 mono_aot_get_method
>   (aot-runtime.c:3097) 2   TestApp                  0x00b346c0
>   mono_jit_compile_method_with_opt (mini.c:5089) 3   TestApp
>     0x00b34c3a mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5639) 4   TestApp
>     0x00ba2b14 mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2790) 5   TestApp
>     0x00ba136a mono_runtime_object_init (object.c:105) 6   TestApp
>     0x00bdfa30 mono_exception_from_name_domain (exception.c:70) 7
>   TestApp                   0x00bdfd3e mono_get_exception_null_reference
>   (exception.c:40) 8   TestApp                  0x00b79944
>   mono_handle_exception_internal + 60 9   TestApp
>     0x00b7a22a mono_handle_exception (mini-exceptions.c:1894) 10  TestApp
>     0x00bab8f6 handle_signal_exception (exceptions-arm.c:559) 11  TestApp
>     0x00102794 MonoTouch_UIKit_UIControlEventProxy_Activated
>   (UIControl.cs:30) 12  TestApp                 0x009d9b14
>   wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr
>   + 192 13  TestApp                 0x00b34f44 mono_jit_runtime_invoke (mini.c:5793) 14  TestApp                    0x00ba2b14
>   mono_runtime_invoke (object.c:2790) 15  TestApp
>     0x00b2b6f0
>   native_to_managed_trampoline_MonoTouch_UIKit_UIControlEventProxy_Activated
>   (:88) 16  CoreFoundation                   0x355763f6 -[NSObject
>   performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 46 17  UIKit
>     0x3306be00 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 56 18 
>   UIKit                             0x3306bdbc -[UIApplication
>   sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 24 19  UIKit
>     0x3306bd9a -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 38 20  UIKit
>     0x3306bb0a -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] +
>   486 21  UIKit                             0x3306c442 -[UIControl
>   touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 470 22  UIKit
>     0x3306a924 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 312 23  UIKit
>     0x3306a312 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 374 24  UIKit
>     0x3305068e -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 350 25  UIKit
>     0x3304ff34 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5820

Comment: it is not "exit". Your App crashed. Real device is not equal to Simulator. Libraries & Architecture are different. What is the error?

Comment: Yes, I know that an app exits when it crashes - and it isn't a graceful shutdown.  I.E. Terminates the app...  And I also know the device isn't the simulator...  It appears to me (as originally stated) that it is a null reference exception - just like I created, but it is like it didn't do the try/catch block at all!

Comment: it might crash at another line of codes. Sad to tell that your crash log does not show anything useful. That's why it is recommended to use native codes, for easy debugging

Comment: If I comment out the Try/catch block then everything works fine... Clearly, there is a problem in the library/compiler code that is generating the exception.. Just creating one and catching it causes the app to terminate (crash, whatever)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're using a crash reporting library (such as TestFlight). These crash reporting libraries will handle null reference exceptions before Xamarin.iOS can, and treat the exception as a crash (thus crashing the app).

You can read a better description here: [How to prevent iOS crash reporters from crashing MonoTouch apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499334/how-to-prevent-ios-crash-reporters-from-crashing-monotouch-apps) (which also has a solution).

Answer (score 0):

The code is `try` block is obviously incorrect. a null object can't call `.ToString()`, and in the `catch` block, the `ex` variable comes from nowhere.

Double check the logic.

```
try {
  // crash something
} catch(Exception) {
  // caught something
}
```

Comment: This button is INTENDED to thrown an exception - in order to test the Log.Exeception() code... However, JUST throwing and catching the exception causes the program to crash...  THIS is the problem I'm trying to address...

Comment: Also, the ex is "used" in a comment :-)

Comment: but you commented out the `Log.Exception()` line. Also, you should use proper try catch block

Comment: What is improper about it?  The (Execption ex) is entirely optional - AND generates a compiler warning...  But, both caused the exact same effect... So, yes, I tried it both ways...

Comment: BTW: I commented out the Log.Exception() line to confirm that it wasn't anything in my code (my other code) that was causing the issue, but strictly a bug in creating/catching an exception inside of a button event.

Answer (score 0):

Well...

This works:

```
try
   {
       throw new Exception("Test Exception");
   }

catch (Exception ex)
   {
   Log.Exception ("Test", ex);  
   }
```

This means that the exception that gets thrown by trying to call `ToString()` on a `null` object actually will take out the whole app! One for the compiler guys... My test now works, and I'm happy with that...

-Chert

Answer (score 0):

As you figured out yourself, if an exception is thrown using `throw new Exception ()`, it's properly caught in the `catch` clause.

The problem here lies in the different ways `null` is treated in `Obj-C` and in `.NET`. In .NET, calling an instance method on a `null` object instance throws a `NullReferenceException`, whereas in `Obj-C` it's totally valid to send a message (invoke a method) to `nil`. The result of the call will be `nil`, and no exception or error will be generated.

In some case like yours, `Xamarin.iOS` can't deal with the `nil` returned by the native code and crash. And you can't catch that exception.

Some whiner will call this a leaky abstraction, but if you're a positive kind of person, just take a mental note for next time.

Comment: What @rolfbjarnekving said. That was the post I was looking for.