# App crashes when Crashlytics catches an exception

Tags: ios, crash, xamarin, crash-reports, crashlytics

I've integrated Crashlytics into my Xamarin.iOS project, Crashlytics starts, application appeared at crashlytics site.
But then, when crashlytics catches exception, it crashes with the next error:

> signal %d, info %p, uapVoid %p
>
> Unable to setup stack %s

I'm starting crashlytics and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` like this ([method description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499334/how-to-prevent-ios-crash-reporters-from-crashing-monotouch-apps)):

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    IntPtr sigbus = Marshal.AllocHGlobal (512);
    IntPtr sigsegv = Marshal.AllocHGlobal (512);

    // Store Mono SIGSEGV and SIGBUS handlers
    sigaction (Signal.SIGBUS, IntPtr.Zero, sigbus);
    sigaction (Signal.SIGSEGV, IntPtr.Zero, sigsegv);

    ...

    Crashlytics.Crashlytics.StartWithAPIKey("myApiKeyHere");
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) => {
        ...
    };

    sigaction (Signal.SIGBUS, sigbus, IntPtr.Zero);
    sigaction (Signal.SIGSEGV, sigsegv, IntPtr.Zero);

    Marshal.FreeHGlobal (sigbus);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal (sigsegv);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an officially supported crash reporter for Xamarin, [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com) just released our bindings here:

http://components.xamarin.com/view/crittercism